# Add linq property selector to Expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I have the following Expression in Linq:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> NextDistinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) 
{
    T previous = default(T);
    bool first = true;
    foreach(T item in items)
    {
        if (first || !Equals(previous, item)) 
        {
            first = false;
            previous = item;
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to add a Selector like this:

```
.NextDistinct(i => i.articlepricehistory_sell)
```

I tried, but the key select doesn't work correctly:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> NextDistinct<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
            Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
        {
            TSource previous = default(TSource);
            bool first = true;
            foreach (TSource item in source)
            {
                if (first || !Equals(previous, item))
                {
                    first = false;
                    previous = item;
                    yield return item;
                }                
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE:**

This is my query i need to do a distinct only using the articlepricehistory_sell column

```
var ArticlesSellHistory = dt.AsEnumerable()
select new
{
   articlepricehistory_sell = articlespricehistory.Field<Double>("articlepricehistory_sell"),
   articlepricehistory_date = articlespricehistory.Field<DateTime>("articlepricehistory_date")
})
.NextDistinct(i => i.articlepricehistory_sell)
.ToList();
```

Result:

```
365 05/09/2015 02:30:31 p.m.
370 11/10/2015 04:19:37 p.m.
369.59  11/10/2015 04:19:54 p.m.
365 11/10/2015 04:20:05 p.m.
365 11/10/2015 04:20:58 p.m.
365 11/10/2015 04:33:22 p.m.
```

Expected Result:

```
365 05/09/2015 02:30:31 p.m.
370 11/10/2015 04:19:37 p.m.
369.59  11/10/2015 04:19:54 p.m.
365 11/10/2015 04:20:05 p.m.
```

Comment: Yeah, your function definition seems right, but you have to use the keySelector parameter

Comment: Please tell me how i can use, i only change the function definition for accept the property selector but i don't how i can use it inside the function.

Comment: Keyselector is now a function that you can call. It takes a parameter of type tsource and returns an object of type tkey.

Comment: I tried: foreach (TSource item in source.Select(keySelector))

Comment: Please see my Updated question, if i only select one column into my query works perfectly but i need to select two columns double, datetime types so That's where the problem starts, because all the dates are different, so I occupied a selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to replace `TSource previous` with `TKey previousKey` and compare it to the current item key (both extracted using the passed selector). Also it's good to allow optionally specifying a comparer for both your functions. The function in question could be like this

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> NextDistinct<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("keySelector");
    if (keyComparer == null) keyComparer = EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
    var previousKey = default(TKey);
    bool first = true;
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        var itemKey = keySelector(item);
        if (first || !keyComparer.Equals(previousKey, itemKey))
        {
            yield return item;
            first = false;
            previousKey = itemKey;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks, It is just what I needed.